# Iterating through a list iin ansible

Tags: python, linux, ansible, jinja2

I would loop over those variables from result given by the playbook mentioned above.

```
LIST=( "bin" "boot" "etc" "lib" "lib64" "opt" "sbin" "srv" "usr" "var" "home" )
```

I already have the tasks which will find all the `mount_point` from `etc/fstab` but i am confused how to iterate trough those variables to get the final result.

```
- name: List all mount points on which an ext file system is mounted
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ansible_facts.mounts | selectattr('fstype','match', '^ext+' | map(attribute='mount')}}"
```

the output should be something like this:

```
/
/boot 
/home
/opt  
/var 
/var
/opt 
/var/tmp
/var/log
/var/log/audit`
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html => basically `loop: "{{ ansible_facts.mounts | selectattr('fstype','match', '^ext+' | map(attribute='mount') }}"`

Comment: be careful, I bet you want `^ext.+` if those `fstype`s are ext3, ext4, etc since `^ext+` matches `ex` and one or more `t` characters

Comment: @Zeitounator thank you for the suggestion.
@mdaniel how about adding this `^ext+[0-9]+` or  `fstype', 'in', ['ext2', 'ext3', 'ext4']` is better?
either i would iterate through those variable `LIST=( "bin" "boot" "etc" "lib" "lib64" "opt" "sbin" "srv" "usr" "var" "home" )`